# where are the sources downloaded for a yocto

Tags: yocto

New to Yocto. Written a simple recipe for a libray. Trying to understand the directory structure. Can't figure out where the files are downloaded and where they are compiled. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your local.conf, you should have `DL_DIR` variable set, it's where recipes are downloaded. Then they are extracted in

`<build>/tmp/work/<arch>/<recipe>/<version>/[git|recipe-version]`

and compiled in

`<build>/tmp/work/<arch>/<recipe>/<version>/build`

They are some exceptions, kernel source for example is in

`<build>/tmp/work-shared/<arch>/kernel-source`